# Finding arc length and binormal vector for a given curve

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, plane-curves

Can somebody show me the arc length of a curve formula, and the binormal vector formula. The curve C with equation $r(t)=(\sqrt{3}\cos t,t,\sqrt{3}\sin t)$

How do you find the arc length from $t=0$ to $t=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and the binormal vector at $t=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I think you mean "binormal" vector, don't you, not "binomial" vector ??

Comment: @user90705 Do you know what the arc length is, by definition?

Comment: length of an arc in space, so a line integral?

Comment: @bubba yes i mean binormal

Comment: Usually that's not the definition, but it ammounts to finding $\int \limits_0^{\pi /2}\Vert r'(t)\Vert dt$.

Comment: @GitGud so what does this formula give $L=\int_a^b \sqrt{r'^2+r^2}~d\theta$

Comment: @user90705 Check the last equality on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating) section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Length of $r$**

  for the length of the curve $r$ you just need to apply the definition found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Length_and_natural_parametrization), i.e.

$$L(r)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\|r'(t)\|^2}dt,$$

denoting by $r'(t)$ the fist derivative of your curve at 'time' $t$, i.e.

$$r'(t)=(-\sqrt{3}\sin t, 1, \sqrt{3}\cos t), $$

which implies $\|r'(t)\|^2=3+1=4$. Integration is now straighforward.

- **Binormal vector $B(t)$**

The binormal vector $B(t)$ to the curve $r$ at $t$ is defined as

$$B(t)= r(t)\times n(t), $$

where $n(t)$ is the normal vector of $r$ at $t$: it is given by

$$n(t)=\frac{q(t)'}{\|q'(t)\|},$$

where $q(t):=\frac{r'(t)}{\|r'(t)\|}$ is the unit tangent vector at $t$.

By definition, the binormal vector $b(t)$ is orthogonal to the plane spanned by $r(t)$ and $n(t)$. Let us compute it.

From the computations of the above section, we have

$$q(t)=\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt{3}\sin t, 1, \sqrt{3}\cos t),$$

which implies

$$q'(t)=\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt{3}\cos t, 0, -\sqrt{3}\sin t) $$
$$\|q'(t)\|^2=\frac{3}{4},$$

and

$$n(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(-\sqrt{3}\cos t, 0, -\sqrt{3}\sin t).$$

We are left with

$$B(t)=r(t)\times n(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(-\sqrt{3}t\sin t, 0, \sqrt{3}t \cos t),$$

which follows from using the definition of cross product, as explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Comment: @user90705 do you need also the binormal vector?

Comment: added to the answer; I hope it helps

Comment: cheers mate it does

Comment: thanks for your answer very conscise, now how would you go about graphing the curve

Comment: To plot is manually is not so easy, but consider that for all $t$, $r_1^2+r_3^2=3$, where the curve at $t$ is the vector $r(t)=(r_1,r_2,r_3)$. In other words, the first and last coordinates lie on a circle of radius $3$. The second component, i.e. $r_2$ increases linearly with $t$. In summary, your curve seems like a... :-)

Comment: and i believe it should be $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ for n(t)

Comment: uhm...but $n(t)=\frac{q'(t)}{\|q'(t)\|}$, where $\|q'(t)\|=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$...

Answer (score 0):

And for the binormal, use the formula for $\mathbf B(t)$ given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binormal_vector#Other_expressions_of_the_frame).